# Recibo "Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined" al pasarle un array a "dom-repeat"

Tags: javascript, polymer

Cuando a un dom-repeat le paso un array que esta dentro de un objeto recibo este error:

```
  "Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"
```

Este es el codigo:

```html
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="hola-mundo">
 <style>
  h1{
   color: blue;
  }
 </style>
 
 <template>
   
  <button on-tap="test">myButton</button>       

  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{myObject.parameters}}">
    <div>{{item.name}}</div>    
  </template>
 </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
 Polymer({
  is: "hola-mundo",
  properties: {
   myObject: {
    type:Object,
    value: {
     parameters: {
      type: Array,
      value: []
     },
     color: {
      type: String,
      value: 'red'
     } 
    }
   }
    
  },
  
  test: function(){
   this.push('myObject.parameters', { 'id': '1', 'name': 'test'});
  },  
 });
</script>
```

Si el array esta fuera del objeto funciona bien, pero necesito que este dentro del objeto.

¿Puede alguien corregir mi código? no doy encontrado el error.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La declaración de las propiedades más del primer nivel no está soportada creo. Prueba a declarar myObject de la siguiente manera y te debe funcionar:

```
properties: {
    myObject: {
        type:Object,
        value: {
            parameters: [],
            color: 'red'
        }
    }
},
```